# I cant ping windows xp from windows 7 but I can do the opposite

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, ping, file-sharing

I have problems connecting windows xp pc, with windows 7 laptop that usethe same router togother, my goal is to be able to share files between the two. the pc with windows xp is connected to the router using an ethernet cable, and the laptop with windows 7 connected to the same router wirless(using wifi). so to check if there is a connections between the two computers,I try using ping, when I ping the windows 7 from windows xp it work, but when I ping windows xp from windows 7 I get request time out, sent:4, recieved: 0 , lost: 4.
the two computers have the same work group.

I searched for a week now for a solution but in vain.
what would go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some steps which might help :

- In Windows 7 Network and Sharing Center, "Change advanced sharing settings"

  - Turn ON network discovery
  - Turn ON file and printer sharing
  - Turn ON sharing in the Public folder sharing section
  - Turn ON password protected sharing
- Ensure Window's File and Printer Sharing is turned on for both computers.
- Create matching user accounts and passwords on all computers.
- Turn off Simple File Sharing (Folder Options > View tab).
- In Windows 7, run `gpedit.msc` and go to
  *Computer Configuration > Windows settings > Security settings > Security options*,
  item "Network Security: LAN Manager Security Level", and set it to
  "Send LM & NTLM responses".
  Ensure that the registry subkey
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`
  contains an entry entry named `SMB1` whose value is
  `1` for Enabled. (Not required if `SMB1` is not present.)

Comment: did what you say but still not working

Comment: On which computer is the shared folder?

Comment: I cant ping to windows xp from windows 7 when putting ping x.x.x.x)windows xp ip), so i dont make a shared folder

Comment: check now and it seems there is a share file in both computers, but same probkem

Comment: also i try ping windows xp to its ip but didnt work as well

Comment: the problem was a SECURITY SOFTWARE, i deleted it and all works fine now, thank you